# data from one source tag has to be mapped to multiple destination tags in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2, biztalk-mapper

I have to map data from one source schema tag data to three tags in the Destination schema. I have used scripting two scripting functoids which take the source tag value as input.

1. the output of first script functoid is mapped to two destination tags.
2. The output of second functoid is mapped to one destination tag.

But the problem is that only one script functoids output is reflected in all three destination tags.

Kindly let me know if you need any more clarification on this.

Comment: Can you post sample schemas and a map that shows what you have?  The explanation isn't sufficient to reproduce it.

Comment: I would have to induce that the functoid that has two destination tags does not provide an output value..